# Prototypical inheritance for cloned object - IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, lodash

I’m trying to clone an object, using lodash’  `_.clone`.

However, I want to keep the prototypical inheritance intact for the cloned object. IE 10 is not letting me access `__proto__` or  even this `Object.setPrototypeOf(toObj, Object.getPrototypeOf(fromObj));` and I don’t want to access via `call` or `apply` on parent object as there are lot of setter and getter method on parent which need to be called from the clone object.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You'd want to start your cloning process with `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(fromObj))`. I don't think lodash does allow extending their functionality, so you'd have to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

After some try, I found this one of my use:

```
/**
 * Shallow clone an object and retains the prototype chain
 * @param   {Object} fromObj Object to be cloned
 * @returns {Object} Cloned Object
 */
function cloneObj(fromObj) {
  var toObj, i;

  if (fromObj && typeof fromObj === 'object') {
    toObj = new fromObj.constructor();

    for (i in fromObj) {
      if (fromObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        toObj[i] = fromObj[i];
      }
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error(fromObj + ' cannot be cloned');
  }

  return toObj;
}
```